# Blender Working Background of a Server

Tags: python, export, import, .fbx, gltf

I'm trying to make a converter that converts FBX files to GLB files. I know that converting some FBX file to GLB file manually is easy. The question is this since I know SO little about the web side of it: Can I make this process automatic which runs in a server like an online converter by using some scripts or so? If yes what is the basic concept of it? In my mind the picture is this:
I build Blender to a Linux based server.(I don't know how). I write some scripts or code (don't know the language) to take the file and convert it to desired file extension.
So can anyone enlighten me about this concept?

Edit: Sorry if tags are inappropiate, I am so new to this concept so please don't delete this question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question is too general for Blender StackExchange, but 1) You don't need to build Blender, just install it using your Linux system's installer. 2) The language is python.  Your script would call the FBX importer, make whatever changes you need, and then call the GLB exporter.  I suggest looking for questions here with the Python or Scripting tags that talk about importing and exporting.  As a starting point you'll need to learn some Python, of course.  But may I ask why you don't just use existing online fbx to gltf converters?

Comment: The reason why I'm not using existing ones is I'm trying to make one of these on my own. I understand the most of the concept BUT that one thing still remains unsolved. There was a miswriting by me I think. I meant install by building... So correct me if I am wrong but I understand concept as this: I install Blender to a Linux based web server then write some scripts to do import and export issues automatically... Am I right?
Thanks a lot for your answer by the way

Comment: Yes.  You don't need to build blender because it has a builtin Python interpreter.  You just need to write a script that uses Blender's `bpy` library and use that script.

Comment: So just to be clear, I'm a bit confused by some irrelevant thing. What is the difference between "build" and "install" by definition. Sorry for the confusion, I'm a bit new to concept.

Comment: Build means that you get the source code and run it through compliers and other tools to create the Blender executable file.  Install means that you copy the Blender executable file (and others) to your PC and put them in various places.